# URL rewriting using servlet Filter forward makes other filters unusable

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, servlet-filters

I want to implement some URL rewriting using a Servlet Filter, similar to what the well known Tuckey's URLrewritefilter. I'd gladly use Tuckey's code, but I have some requirements that it cannot fulfil.

Anyways, I created a servlet filter on top of the filter chain like this

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>URLRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.my.app.URLRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>URLRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
more filters with similar mappings
```

In the filter I wrap the response, for overwriting the encodeURL methods, which works great!

My problem is with the inbound URLs:
I'll try to match any request url with my inbound rewriting rules and if it matches, I either send a redirect (with works) or a forward.
In case of a forward, all the below filters are not processed, because they have the default dispatchers mapping `DispatcherType.REQUEST` only. And this is correct, they don't need to run on each and every forward to all of my JSP, etc. I just want them to process an incoming request once. I know I could just add `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher><dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` to every of the 20 following filters, but that doesn't feel right.

I tried to trick the container, by wrapping the request and overwriting the `getDispatcherType()` method to return `DispatcherType.REQUEST` instead of `FORWARD`. But that doesn't work.

I bet Tuckey's implementation has the same problem, because it's also using forwards.

Is there any nice way around this? Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you try to do the request wrapping? In another filter applied before your rewrite filter or in your actual rewrite filter?

Comment: In my actual rewrite filter, passing the wrapped request in to the forward in hope that I could influence the way the filter mappings are matched by returning DispatcherType.REQUEST in the respective getter method. But as it turns our the request is unwrapped in the RequestDispatcher.forward logic (I looked at the source code).